# 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, anaconda

For quite some time, I'm trying to download Anaconda and add it to my PATH.

I did select the option 'Add to PATH' when installing it. I did it twice, because first I thought the problem was in the map name, which contains spaces. Then I downloaded it in a map which didn't contain spaces. All of this didn't work. Do you know what to do?

This is my PATH:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Pythonthings;C:\Pythonthings\Scripts;C:\Pythonthings\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Pythonthings\Library\usr\bin;C:\Pythonthings\Library\bin;C:\Pythonthings;C:\Pythonthings\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Pythonthings\Library\usr\bin;C:\Pythonthings\Library\bin;C:\Pythonthings\Scripts;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.3\bin;
```

Anaconda is installed under C:\Pythonthings and C:\Users\Jeroen Kodde

Comment: Did you restart your console after changing the path?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.